# Get Cell from a DataTable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, datatables

I am working with DataTables. And I have one that is the following:

[image]

Ok, what I want to do is for example **if I am in the level 1 (COSC-1218-SIT41SCH), I want to get the cell of "Cantidad" of level 2 in red**. ***For example, the cells are C3, C4, C5, C6 and C7***. How can I do this with datatables? with .Select or have to use loops? I am completely new with datatables.

Comment: I think this is more an algorythmic question that a question related to datatable.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to get the row index of "COSC-1218-SIT41SCH". And then traverse the DataTable to get "Cantidad". Here is a simple demo you can refer to.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// Define a list to store the row index of "COSC-1218-SIT41SCH"
List<int> list = new List<int>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Connection String"))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From GetCellTest", conn);
        sda.Fill(ds, "T_Class");
    }

    dt = ds.Tables["T_Class"];

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dr["Level1"].ToString() == "COSC-1218-SIT41SCH")
        {
            list.Add(dt.Rows.IndexOf(dr));
        }
    }

    // Filter the first one
    list.Remove(0);

    // Get the value of "Cantidad"
    foreach(var i in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i]["Cantidad"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, but in this way I have the "amount" of the entire level 2, so I have the Quantity column of "COSC-1218-sit41sch" but the Quantity column of "COSC-12-IF43SCH" too and I just want to get the red values, i.e., the values under COSC-1218-sit41sch.

Comment: I used `dr["Level1"].ToString() == "COSC-1218-SIT41SCH"`, it only filters "Level2" that meets the conditions rather than all.

Comment: But if we didn't know the Level 1 value, how could we get the red values?

Comment: What are your known parameters?

Comment: I have edited the post with all columns, I can know where is every column and the values of every cell if I do this: DataTable.Rows[j][i] ... with a loop I can iterate over the DataTable